# Invalid state: The Flow Controller is initializing the Data Flow

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying out a test scenario to add a new node to the already existing cluster (for now 1-node) using external zookeeper.

I'm constantly getting the below repeated lines, and on UI "Invalid state: The Flow Controller is initializing the Data Flow."

> 2022-02-28 17:51:29,668 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.c.n.LeaderElectionNodeProtocolSender Determined that Cluster Coordinator is located at nifi-02:9489; will use this address for sending heartbeat messages

> 2022-02-28 17:51:29,668 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.p.AbstractNodeProtocolSender Cluster Coordinator is located at nifi-02:9489. Will send Cluster Connection Request to this address

> 2022-02-28 17:51:37,572 INFO [Cleanup Archive for default] o.a.n.c.repository.FileSystemRepository Successfully deleted 0 files (0 bytes) from archive

> 2022-02-28 17:52:36,914 INFO [Write-Ahead Local State Provider Maintenance] org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog@13c90c06 checkpointed with 1 Records and 0 Swap Files in 4 milliseconds (Stop-the-world time = 1 milliseconds, Clear Edit Logs time = 1 millis), max Transaction ID 1

> 2022-02-28 17:52:37,581 INFO [Cleanup Archive for default] o.a.n.c.repository.FileSystemRepository Successfully deleted 0 files (0 bytes) from archive

NiFi-1.15.3 is being used (unsecure setup)

It seems that cluster coordinator is not running on mentioned port for node already in cluster. This I thought from timeout prospective, but new node is able to detect that a cluster coordinator is present at the mentioned node. (How to solve this?)

> nc (netcat) is also timing out for the same port

Comment: new node’s flow.xml.gz must be the same as others, so try to delete new node’ s flow file. it must be re-created by coordinator.

Comment: Hi @yaprak, clearing flow.xml.gz won't help here. I have tried it also, it has some other issue (to know why ports are not able to communicate with each other)